# Count frequency of a value and add it to a new column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Let me preface by saying I know that this has been asked a bunch on stack, but my values are timestamps and the timezone keeps disapearing when I try the one method I think will work.

I have a dataframe with timestamps and some of the unique timestamps repeat. I am trying to create a new column that counts how many times a timestamp appears.

The best solution I thought of includes creating a table and then joining the table back to the original dataframe. However, I lose the timezone of the timestamp when creating the table and then cannot join it back.

```
n_occur <- data.frame(table(as.POSIXct(df$detection_timestamp_utc)))

left_join(df, n_occur, by = c("detection_timestamp_utc" = "Var1"))
```

The error message I get for this line of code is that both timestamp columns are incompatible because Var1 (created from the previous line) is "<factor<3fb99>>>." No idea what that means. Would greatly appreciate some guidance on either how to get my timezone to stick around or how to count frequency of occurrence in dplyr.

Comment: Try `mutate(df, n_occur = n(), .by =detection_timestamp_utc) `

Comment: @MAurélio This added a column named "n_occur" that has the same value and contains the nrow of my df. It also added a column named ".by" that is a duplicate of "detection_timestamp_utc"

Comment: You need the latest version of `dplyr` package. If You can't update it just use `group_by(df, detection_timestamp_utc) %>% mutate(n_occur = n())`